# ¿Por qué me sale un error de que no encuentra la columna NOMBRE, si realmente sí existe en la tabla?

Tags: sqlite3

Estoy uniendo información de la tabla *clientes_Base6* con la tabla *Consolidado*. Estoy utilizando el gestor DB Browser for sqlite; visualicé en el panel de sqlite en la opción de Browse Data y la tabla *clientes_Base6* sí tiene el campo NOMBRE así tal cual.

Adjunto el script:

```
INSERT INTO Consolidado(Nombre_Completo,Numero_Identificacion,Telefono_Fijo,Telefono_Movil,Direccion,email) 
SELECT NOMBRE,CEDULA CLIENTE,TELEFONO,CELULAR,DIRECCION,CORREO ELECTRONICO
FROM  clientes_Base6


SELECT Nombre_Completo, Numero_Identificacion,Telefono_Fijo,Telefojo_Movil,Direccion,email FROM Consolidado 
í
```

Answer (score 0):

inicialmente creo que el insert no lo estás haciendo bien, la sintaxis es:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

te recomiendo hacer un `select * from Consolidado`
para verificar los nombres de sus campos, lo mismo de tu tabla `clientes_base7` para que revises ambas.

Comment: los datos que voy a insertar en la tabla Consolidado necesito traerlos de la tabla clientes_Base6

Answer (score 0):

Para poder insertar un registro, tienes que usar `INSERT INTO` y `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO Consolidado(Nombre_Completo, Numero_Identificacion, Telefono_Fijo, Telefono_Movil, Direccion, email) VALUES('nombre', 'identificacion', 'telefono', 'movil', 'direccion', 'correo');
```

Una vez la inserción se haya hecho, ahí puedes consultar el registro en la tabla Consolidado:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Consolidado 
   WHERE Numero_Identificacion = 'identificacion'
```